# SyntaxError: Unexpected token { at Object.parse (native) NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, parsing

I'm trying to parse a JSON string : ( with JSON.parse() )

[{"number":0}]

But it shows me the message : SyntaxError: Unexpected token { at Object.parse (native)
http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/789845screengladys.png

My JSON seems to be correct, does everyone have an ideas how to fix it ? 
Thank you in forward for your help :)

Comment: It looks like the error is on `[`, not `{`. There must be something before that character that is causing it to be invalid.

Comment: the json string comes from an ajax request with xmlhttprequest, but when I output the string, I have nothing before [, just the json ! http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/896329alarme.png

Comment: Are you using the right function? The stack trace says `Object.parse`, but you should be using `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Yes i'm sure! here is my code : if (xhralarme.readyState == 4 && xhralarme.status == 200) 
                            {
                            
                                alarmes = JSON.parse(xhralarme.responseText);

                            }

Comment: Hmm, do `typeof(xhralarme.responseText)` and `xhralarme.responseText.length` give the values you expect?

Comment: Yes! If I print them with and "console.log", it's just the value I want... Very strange problem

Comment: try to print to the console: `typeof(xhralarme.responseText)`. what do you get?